# Intel xdk save canvas image ( jpg ) to camera roll (not from camera capture)

Tags: jquery, cordova, canvas, android-camera, intel-xdk

I am using Intel XDK and making a game which can change layer into a single DIV. after user choose proper layer, I had function which use drawImage to merge into single image.

```
$('#design-container').children('img').each(function(){
     c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

});
```

Now it is display correctly on my app, but what I can do if I want to save this image into camera roll ?

Now I purely use app_framework and jQuery only. should I include phonegapp to work?

Answer (score 0):

In the Intel XDK you can use the [intel.xdk camera object](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/492889). Also, the [Cordova file object](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) may be of value.